# Use a textbox to store a numeric counter in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to count with a TextBox.
Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        OrainsProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        If OrainsProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
            Timer3.Start()
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OrainsTheme1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OrainsTheme1.Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer2.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
        OrainsProgressBar1.Increment(-1)
        If OrainsProgressBar1.Value = 0 Then
            Timer1.Start()
            Timer3.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OrainsButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OrainsButton1.Click
        OrainsTextBox1.Text += 100
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        OrainsTextBox1.Text += 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

But I have an error with `OrainsTextBox1.Text += 1`. VB says:

> 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

What is the problem?

Comment: clarify your question......!!!

Comment: Put the statement `Option Strict On` as the first line of your code. If will flag the code that can cause these errors (in this case, treating a String as a number). Correct the code that is flagged, and you should not have these problems again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing like this OrainsTextBox1.Text += 1

do like this OrainsTextBox1.Text = Val(OrainsTextBox1.Text) + 1

Because .Text is string. Which will append the 1s as "11111111"

Answer (score 1):

In the .Net world, the data types of things matter a lot. Strings (like the `.Text` property) are **NOT** numbers. You need to convert. Even if someone only enters the digits 0-9 into the textbox, that's still a *string* of numeric *characters*, rather than a number. And what should happen if someone enters random text into that textbox that won't convert to a number type at all?

For this code, I suggest building a property, like this:

```
Private _orainsValue As Double
Public Property OrainsValue As Double
    Get
       Return _orainsValues
    End Get
    Set
         _orainsValue = Value
         OrainsTextBox1.Text = _orainsValue.ToString()
    End Set
End Property
```

That will let you write code like this and have the expected result shown to the user:

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    OrainsVale += 1
End Sub
```

Note that it does mean you will want to mark the TextBox disabled,though, because this doesn't account for user data entry.